# How to get the Hidden Field value which is set by JQuery after Page Load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, hidden-field

Initially, ASP.NET page renders(or set) an empty value on Page_Load and later on JQuery method sets the value when an user inputs data. I'm trying to get the value that is set by JQuery method when ASP.NET Button is clicked.

I set the value in Hidden Field using JQuery

> $('#MyHiddenField').val('valueToStore');

And I'm trying to get the value from code behind C#

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var myValue = MyHiddenField.Value 
}
```

But the **myValue** is always **empty**

What am i missing?

Comment: Try to get value on button click event

Comment: u need to use $('#<%= MyHiddenField.ClientID %>').val('valuetostore');

Comment: I set the MyHiddenField as ClientIDMode="Static"

Comment: @SeehyungLee view state of controls are loaded at page load event. At Page_Init controls only initialize's,because of this u are not able to get the value on  Page_Init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

try to het value on button click

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var myValue = MyHiddenField.Value 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="xml" runat="server" />
```

**JQUERY**

Sets Value to the hidden field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var booking="FEtch value from asp.net hidden field";
$("#<%= xml.ClientID %>").val(booking);
}
```

Retrieving Value from Hidden Field

**C#**

In button click

```
string result=xml.value;//xml is the id of hidden field.
```

**Notes**

```
1.Priority is must.
2.Assigning values must be done first only then fetching will not return null values.
3.Give break points and test it.
```

If you found this as useful and cleared your issues mark as answer and give upvotes.